# Where can I find this kind of sugar free and low sodium biscuit?

Tags: canada, switzerland, food-and-drink

**Issue**

I grew up in Switzerland where I ate [these biscuits (Blevita from Migros)](https://produkte.migros.ch/blevita-5-korngebaeck-mit-sesam-110181500000)  with a glass of milk every night before going to bed. I am a bit addicted to these simple biscuits :)

I have now been living in Vancouver, BC, Canada for 2 years and I fail to find biscuits that are in any way similar. **Do you know where I could find similar biscuits?**

**Description of the biscuits**

[The above link](https://produkte.migros.ch/blevita-5-korngebaeck-mit-sesam-110181500000) gives the following information about nutritional facts (German only).

[image]

- They contain very little sugar.
- They contain little salt (in comparison to anything I could find so far).
- They are much thicker, more dense and solid than standard crackers.
- They quickly suck up all the spit (hence the glass of milk).
- They have a good taste of sesame but I would not be too picky if the substitute you suggest taste flax, oat, spelt or whatever.

Comment: You haven't been able to find something similar in a large grocery store? Triskets are similar in the US, but many US grocery stores carry a lot of European and other style crackers/biscuits/cookies and the like. Have you tried IKEA's shop?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know Ikea relatively well and I don't they have such biscuits but I haven't looked specifically for it. I did not know Triskets. They look more fragile (full of air) and from the nutritional facts have 3 times asmuch salt. But I'll give it a try tonight.

Comment: Triskets are very salty--look for low sodium ones, but I bet they'll have more sugar.

Comment: I had to double-check this. Nabisco in the US that markets similar crackers to yours as "BelVita". Check some stores online to see if they carry them. I'll try to write up an answer tonight if no one else does.

Comment: Funny as the names are so much alike. From [here](http://www.snackworks.com/products/product-detail.aspx?product=4400003416) I get that Belvita (from Nabisco) has 7 times more sugar than Blevita (from Migros). Thanks a lot for your help though, I appreciate! Any other idea?

Comment: Someone on Amazon.ca is likely importing them, but the price/shipping may be quite expensive!

Comment: I think this product is only produced by Migros in Switzerland. So far, I just ask friends that are visiting to fill up their luggage with these biscuits - which of course is always a solution when you can't find a product as expatriate - but I am hoping I could find an easier solution. Also, it sounds a bit sad and surprising if there exist no small biscuit that are not completely filled with sugar and/or salt in Canada (or USA).

Comment: @mkennedy: Spelling is "Triscuit".  And neither the [original](http://www.snackworks.com/products/product-detail.aspx?product=4400002795) nor the ["hint of salt" (low-sodium)](http://www.snackworks.com/products/product-detail.aspx?product=4400002802) variant contains any added sugar.  Only ingredients are wheat, oil and salt.  (I note that they apparently also contain NaN grams of fat per serving.)

Comment: @Remi.b: you might compare these: Crunchmaster Multi-seed Cracker (0g sugar, 110mg sodium), Blue Diamond Almond Nut Thins/Sesame (1g sugar, 135mg sodium), Mary's Gone Crackers Seed Crackers (0g sugar, 150mg sodium), Kashi TLC Tasty Little Crackers (3 g sugar, 200mg sodium)

Comment: Through trial and error (I bought many different types of thins) I end up finding [stoned wheat thins](https://www.google.ca/search?q=stoned+wheat+thins&espv=2&biw=1161&bih=753&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFsJTj3MvOAhVC4WMKHZ4-AZIQ_AUIBigB&dpr=1) which is for the moment the closest thing to Blevita (Migros) I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be able to find this exact same brand imported in Vancouver, but it sounds like you're open to substitutes. Here's a few things I'd look into:

- Vancouver has a Whole Foods Market. That brand of stores often carries healthier snacks including (likely) similar "multigrain thins" as these would be called.
- Amazon carries a few similar multigrain biscuits with low added salt and low fat content such as Finn Crisps or Suzie's whole grain thin cakes, with nutritional information to compare.

Comment: Through trial and error (I bought many different types of thins) I end up finding [stoned wheat thins](https://www.google.ca/search?q=stoned+wheat+thins&espv=2&biw=1161&bih=753&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFsJTj3MvOAhVC4WMKHZ4-AZIQ_AUIBigB&dpr=1) which is for the moment the closest thing to Blevita (Migros) I could find.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you go to your nearest Walmart and try out some of the (many!) cracker products there; you should be able to find something reasonably close to Blevita there.  At least at http://www.walmart.ca/en/pantry-households-pets/chips-snacks/cookies-crackers/N-347 they seem to have a *very* large assortment to choose from!